# Is there a way I can tell if IE7 is rendering a page in Standards mode or Quirks mode

Tags: html, css, standards, quirks-mode

I'm having a bit of trouble w/ some CSS on a page. It's valid CSS and Strict HTML. It renders fine in every* browser except for IE (I have only tried 7). Is there a way to tell if it's rendering the page in Quirks or Standard mode? I suspect it may be doing quirks mode, as that's about the only explanation I can think of.

*Opera, Chrome, Safari, Firefox ... not really every, but close enough.

Comment: `document.compatMode` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627097/how-to-tell-if-a-browser-is-in-quirks-mode)

Comment: have you looked at this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link Kenny. I don't use Javascript much so that really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Within IE, you can open up the developer tools (Tools->Developer Tools, or F12), and along the top, it will list Document Mode: .  You can see there in what mode the browser is rendering your page.

One word of caution: IE likes to treat pages on your local network differently from pages on the internet.  Specifically, it will sometimes default into compatibility view for pages on the local intranet.