# Dojo 1.7.2 drag and drop bug - "mouseButtons.isLeft"

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I am on dojo 1.7.2 and trying to use drag and drop for the first time.

In dojo/dnd/Source.js, in the function `_legalMouseDown`, there is this line:

```
// accept only the left mouse button
if(!dojo.mouseButtons.isLeft(e)){ return false; }
```

Comically, `.isLeft` is returning false even when I press the left mouse button.

This completely breaks the drag and drop functionality.

I've replaced the code locally with `if(!e.button==0){return false;}`, and this seems to be working.

There seem to be multiple implementations of `.isLeft` in dojo, some of them are doing `==0` and others are doing `&1`.

**Question:** Have I found a bug, or am I doing something silly?

If it helps to know, I've tested in Chrome (Version 20.0.1132.47) and Firefox (Version 13.0.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your page using quirks mode?  This is the known issue with quirks mode.

http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15404

Your solution may have broken other browsers (IE), so make sure you test the browsers that your application supports.

Comment: What is quirks mode? How do I know if my page is using it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627097/how-to-tell-if-a-browser-is-in-quirks-mode

Comment: Thanks for the lesson. I am in quirks mode in both Chrome and FF. As is mentioned in the trac ticket, .isLeft is just buggy. I appreciate your time.

Comment: +1, was just about to write same answer, set the correct DOCTYPE and run document through validation service and it will fix things.