# The Appearance of li is distorted in IE8 while in mozilla firefox it is correct

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, html-lists

Following is the piece of CSS

```
#innerHeaders 
{
    background-color: #026062;
    height: 33px;
    left: 269px;
    position: relative;
    top: 17px;
    width: 755px;
}

ul li
{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle; 
}

ul li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left:45.5px;
}

ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;  
}

.topBtns
{
    background-image:url(../images/topBtnsBg.png);
    width:128px;
    height:33px;
}
```

Following is the HTML code

```
<div id="innerHeaders">
    <ul>
        <li id="homeBtn" class="topBtns"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li id="aboutBtn" class="topBtns"><a href="#" onClick="aboutData();">About</a></li>
        <li id="feedBackBtn" class="topBtns"><a href="xyz@abc.com">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The above li is displayed as the Home About and Feedback button inline in the Firefox browser but in IE8 the Home About and Feedback overlap each other.

following are the respective screenshots
[image: IE]
[image: Firefox]

Comment: My guess is that IE8 is in quirks mode due to lack of a doctype. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110646/ie8-display-inline-block-not-working

Comment: I had seen this earlier and tried but the same was of no help. Can you please elaborate on how to use <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> as even this doesn't work!

Comment: You just put it at the very top of the page, before the opening `<html>` tag. `<!DOCTYPE html>` works just as well (that's the doctype for HTML 5). But there are other things besides lack of a doctype that can trigger quirks mode. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/627124/560114) for how to check if a browser is in quirks mode.

Answer (score 2):

In "li" I have just added float (*float:left;), so that it shows correctly in ie7. And under "ul li a" you have to remove "position:absolute;" and just add line height (line-height:34px;). Hope it show correctly in all browser as you want.

```
ul li
   {
    display:inline-block;
    *float:left;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
   }

    ul li a
    {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    /*position:absolute;*/
    top: 7px;
    left:45.5px;
    line-height:34px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is not right.
Often time the issue with IE is that your parent elements do not have layout. 
This is known as an haslayout issue.
You can read about this more in this article: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout

Try defining the heights and widths of all the parent elements. 
Also the absolute values could be causing a problem.
Maybe you could explain more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: As far as I remember `hasLayout` was a problem in IE 6, much less so in IE 7 and disappeared afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There is some error in your css file which have made correct. jsFiddle url also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H95fU/2/).

```
ul li
       {
        display:inline-block;
        *float:left;
        color:#FFF;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
       }

        ul li a
        {
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#FFF;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        /*position:absolute;*/
        top: 7px;
        left:45.5px;
        }
```

Comment: A short description/explanation of the changes would probably be helpful. This is just a code dump which makes it quite hard to see where the problem was originally.

Comment: The position: absolute has been commented in ul li a and float: left is added in ul li but this doesn't work