# Javascript doesn't work in Chrome when DOCTYPE is declared

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, doctype

I am working with an old site that uses javascript for a dropdown menu on mouseover.  The menu works fine in Chrome but stops working when I add `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which was previously missing.

I understand that the javascript is probably old and outdated, but it does work fine without the doctype declared.  Is there a quick way to fix this site without finding a new script?

```
<script src="/js/script_menus.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script_dropdown.js"></script>

<td><a onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore();FW_startTimeout();"
onMouseOver="window.FW_showMenu(window.fw_menu_1,51,109);
MM_swapImage('img2','','img/nav_02_over.gif',1);"   href="productinfo.html">
<img src="img/nav_02.gif" width="102" height="26" name="img2"></a></td>
```

*Update*

I know this doesn't answer the question, but I have decided to kill this silly javascript menu and write it with CSS.  So the problem at hand is going to be solved.

Comment: try transitional doctype

Comment: If it's an old site, I guess HTML5 is not the correct doctype for the document ? Try html4 transitional doctype.

Comment: There is the possiblity that the site uses some JS quirks which are only available in the so-called "quirks mode" which is triggered when no standard doctype was given.

Comment: @ComFreek: Chrome has a "quirks-mode"? That surprises me. I thought only IE did.

Comment: You will need to debg the code and see where it goes wrong. Nothing we can do to help you without specifics.

Comment: @cookiemonster Every browser has a quirks mode.

Comment: @cookiemonster Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/627124/603003) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types).

Comment: Posted the code per comments above.  Thanks!

Comment: @ComFreek: Thanks, I had just skimmed the wikipedia page. Glad to say I have zero experience working in such a mode. :-)

Comment: @KnocksX I don't see any mistakes in your code. There may be some in the script files, of course.

Comment: Ugh  More mickey-mouse scripts.  Damn you dreamweaver, damn you!

Comment: script_dropdown.js is a pretty long file, so not sure if I can post it here

Answer (score 4):

I'd try using the transitional doctype, like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

because I'm guessing that your site has out of date HTML and Javascript elements, and that will give you a pretty loose doctype that lets pretty much anything go

It looks like you have code with `window.FW_showMenu`, and the only site I could find information about that easily was [this one](http://www.holtenwood.bc.ca/computing/popup/), which looks like its about twice as old as me(seriously).

It also seems to have been generated by DreamWeaver, so I think the simplest thing
 to do that would provide most support into the future would be to replace it with jQuery or pure CSS dropdown menus

Comment: Tried the declaration above, the code is still broken.  Yep, it's old. :)

Comment: Well if it worked with no doctype, just leave the doctype out :)

Comment: But honestly I'd just replace it with new dropdown menus

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not about javascript but DOM structure. When you don't add any DOCTYPE decleration browsers tend to work in quirks mode which changes the behaviour of the DOM. If you do not want to change anything in the code try to use HTML4 DOCTYPE transitional, and add no decleration if it is still not working. 
But I suggesst to modify the code so it creates a DOM structure that's compatible with the latest DOCTYPEs.

Comment: Declaring transitional DOCTYPE did not fix the situation, and the javascript is over my head :/

Comment: @KnocksX why do you want to add DOCTYPE declaration then?

Comment: I want to bring it into compliance as much as possible without breaking anything.  For example, it didn't have charset specified previously, which potentially makes it open to scripting attacks.  Just want to eliminate as much of that as possible.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing the scripts first. But I can tell that in quirks mode, body height is 100% by default while in standards mode it's determined by the content. This might be a point to start. I feel like it's displaying something but probably with zero height. Also open the browser console by pressing F12 and be sure that you're not getting any javascript errors when you try in the standards mode.

Comment: I am rewriting the whole menu in CSS and killing this ridiculous javascript.  Thank you for the help!