# simplemodal with jQuery 1.10.2 not working in IE due to quirks mode being detected incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, simplemodal

I'm using simplemodal 1.4.4 with jQuery 1.10.2 and am getting 'Not implemented' errors in IE8. This is due to simplemodal incorrectly detecting that IE is in quirks mode and executing the 'fixIE' function that is supposed to fix issues in IE6 and IE7 but errors in IE8 (and presumably IE9+ too).

simplemodal does the following check for ieQuirks:

```
browser.ieQuirks = browser.msie && !$.support.boxModel;
```

The problem is that $.support.boxModel has been [removed](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13977) from jQuery 1.10 so `!$.support.boxModel` is always returning true.

I'm wondering what the best way to detect quirks mode is in IE so I can replace `!$.support.boxModel`?

Comment: just provide the boxModel value yourself before using the plugin

Comment: Or you could just replace that detection in the plugin’s code with a working one … http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627097/how-to-tell-if-a-browser-is-in-quirks-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest version of Simple Modal [1.4.4] uses $.support.boxModel, [Line 239] which is not supported from Jquery 1.10.*

To resolve this problem replace following line:

```
// Line 240: browser.ieQuirks = browser.msie && !$.support.boxModel;
```

with

```
browser.ieQuirks = browser.msie && (document.compatMode === "BackCompat");
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what jquery took away, you can insert it back in if you want to

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = div.style.paddingLeft = "1px";

document.body.appendChild( div );
jQuery.support.boxModel = div.offsetWidth === 2;
```