# bootstrap doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a static website project, which is using html5, css3 and the bootstrap framework. In Firefox everything looks great, but in Internet Explorer 8 the site is totally damaged.

Two things are not working properly:

- The main menu is not available
- the teaser boxes are falling out of the layout.

I have already tested the following standard failures:

- website is running in compatibility mode for Internet Explorer
- HTML5shiv.js and respond.js are stored on my own server and not loaded via cdn
- I have set alerts to check that all scripts are running
- HTML is valid
- Site run in Standards mode and not quirks mode

I have tried to find out what is happening with the site with these tools:

- IE debugger
- additionally check it with IETester
- Firebug

Do you have any suggestions?

My project can be viewed [here](http://zugeschmiert.de/test/badow/index.html).

Comment: You should add `html5shiv` first of all i think for IE browsers and **change the compatibility mode to Default IE8 mode.**

Comment: Compatibility mode is probably causing the browser to load in IE7 mode. Check that your browser emulation settings point to IE8 via developer tools.

Comment: Try adding this: <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: @Deceiver they are loading html5shiv.js if the browser is lower than IE8

Comment: @athms The issue is also in the normal Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: @Nickname Do you experience the same behavior on any other Bootstrap powered website?

Comment: @Jai html5shiv is loaded at first of all, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @YannickBlondeau I testet bootstrap examples and they work normal and an other bootstrap project of mine is also working normal.

Comment: Do you know if your site makes IE to get into quirks mode? You could have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/627124/1374267) to figure this out...

Comment: @YannickBlondeau I did an live update and the site in standards mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the two bugs by myself. I solved the first issue "The main menu is not available" with an additional css file for IE through fixing the z-index in combination with postion absolute.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link href="css/ie8fix.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

CSS content for ie8fix.css:

```
.nav{position: absolute; z-index:999;}
```

The second issue was not really a bug, because one box where higher then all others and that was the reason why the box fall out of the design. So I correct the height value (in my case: delete a html break) and it works fine now.