# CSS author class rule overriden by element browser native rule

Tags: css, css-cascade

**`font-size` CSS rule defined by class rule (`.dropdown-menu`) was overridden by build-in browser element rule (`table`). How is that possible?**

I work on [Cockpit](http://cockpit-project.org/) plugin that uses [PatternFly](https://www.patternfly.org/) styles. My label element (selected line in screenshot) has too large `font-size` that was inherited from indirect parent element `table`. The table surprisingly doesn't inherit value of property `font-size` from its parent elements (defined for `div.dropdown` in `.dropdown` definition) however it takes it directly from browser stylesheet. I wonder how is it possible, doesn't it violate CSS cascade - to use browser definition instead on inherit from parent element?

It works this way consistently in Chrome 51 and Firefox 46.

[image: Dev tools screenshot]

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8ru2s40z/) is simplified JsFiddle demo that seems to work correctly (i.e. differently).

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp) `font-size` rule is inherited and according to [css specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) browser styles should have lower priority.

Comment: Check to see if you're in quirksmode, which could be causing this inheritance issue. If you're in strict mode, this should not be occurring.

Comment: `document.compatMode` returns `CSS1Compat` thus I guess it's in strict mode (according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/627124/639687). Now I probably miss something about how css rules are applied. Can you please explain why the `font-size` value was picked from browser style sheet instead of inherited? And compare it to the linked JsFiddle example where it was not?

Comment: @AndyHoffman You were right, it was a quirks mode in iframe. That's why root document's `compatMode` returned `CSS1Compat`. Thank you for a hint. Would you like to put it in an answer I can accept?

Comment: Done. Thanks, @czerny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you're document is in [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html), which could be causing the inheritance issue. If the document is in strict mode, this should not be occurring.