# make ie9 ignore media queries or obey min-width rule

Tags: css

Is there anyway that I can make IE9 ignore media queries or obey min-width?

I have a site that I have used media queries for responsive design for mobile devices and they work great, they also work great in all modern browsers.  The problem is that I have some users that are using quite old browsers (some are still using IE6 believe it or not, no fault of their own and completely unavoidable) so I have a conditional style sheet for IE9 and set the min-width of the page because I don't want any of the media queries I have used to apply to those browsers.

```
body{
    min-width:1000px !important;
}
```

Both IE9 and and IE8 are obeying all of the rules I have put in the conditional stylesheet except IE9 which is ignoring the min-width rule for the body.  That means when it is resized the media rules kick in and kill the layout.

Is there a reason why IE9 would ignore min-width or is there a conditional statement I can use so the media queries don't apply to IE9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to put these old browser targets into conditional comments in your HTML that reference different stylesheets or attach unique classes to your `<html>` element for targeting:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><html lang="en"><![endif]-->
```

And then you can specifically disable or enable certain CSS with the classes:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .ie9 .yourNormalTarget {
        width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I can't see how this will make IE9 obey min-width when it is already in css file targeted at ie9?

Answer (score 1):

Tough to know without seeing your code, but you could be in quirks mode. Make sure that you have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` added to prevent that.

Comment: Hi, I do have that

Comment: Just to be sure quirks mode isn't the issue, you can do the check detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/627124/5999346

Comment: Thanks, thats a useful trick and it confirms I'm in standard mode.