# MDL nav bar icon issue

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

From getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section

I opened link to

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEoBqG

When I saved html code and opened it in few browsers locally. I see that menu button is mispositioned.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Simple header with scrollable tabs. -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Tab 1</a>
          <a href="#scroll-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 2</a>
          <a href="#scroll-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 3</a>
          <a href="#scroll-tab-4" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 4</a>
          <a href="#scroll-tab-5" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 5</a>
          <a href="#scroll-tab-6" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 6</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="scroll-tab-1">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-2">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-3">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-4">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-5">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-6">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How I can fix the misposition of menu icon? Why it looks good on codepen but not locally?

[screenshot with mispositioned icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SljWR.png)

Comment: That's terribly weird... like chrome is treating line-height differently in these two scenarios. Can't figure out what's wrong. As long as it stays ok on your web page, you are good. Otherwise, play with line-height of your <i> (burger icon) node to center the icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between Codepen code and your code is the the missing `<!DOCTYPE html>`. At first, you might wonder, so what? sure the browser can handle it, right?. The truth is that, **omitting `<!DOCTYPE html>` forces your browser to render your page in `Quirks Mode`**.

So, what can go wrong in quirks mode? A lot of things can go wrong in quirks mode. I suspect that flexbox does not work as intended in your case (I will look into it and come back later).

Some useful info:

- [**MDN: Quirks Mode and Standards Mode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode)
- [**MDN: Mozilla Quirks Mode Behavior**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mozilla_quirks_mode_behavior)
- [**How to tell if a browser is in “quirks” mode?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627097/how-to-tell-if-a-browser-is-in-quirks-mode)
- [**Why does my div height 100% work only when DOCTYPE is removed?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214152/why-does-my-div-height-100-work-only-when-doctype-is-removed)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my Monday morning.

Comment: Np, glad it helped ;)