# What is the reason for body width becoming ~15px less wide from this html code?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage which has the html code for one page below. This part of the page's html makes it offset by 15px to the left for no reason. But it annoys me that when i go onto another page on the website, it offsets.

I checked with F12 and on this page body is 1068px wide, on all others, its 1085.

So I've been trying to figure this one out and I could not. I managed to narrow the issue down to this html part:

```
<div class="torzs" id="articleGroup">

            <article class="hirek">
                <div class="artDatum">Date</div>
                <h3>title</h3>
                <p>bla</p>
                <p>bla<strong>bla</strong></p>
            </article>
            <article class="hirek">
                <div class="artDatum">date</div>
                <h3>title</h3>
                <p>bla</p>
                <ul><li>bla1</li><li>bla2</li><li>bla3</li><li>.bla4</li></ul>
                <p>bla</p>
                <p>bla<strong>bla!</strong></p>
                <p>blabla</p>
            </article>
            <article class="hirek">
                <div class="artDatum">date</div>
                <h3>bla</h3>
                <p>bla</p>
                <p>bla</p>
                <p>bla</p>
            </article>

        </div>
```

I deleted all the css from the page, and the issue persisted, so it should be coming from html, right? It is very annoying that all other pages are offset by this little 15-ish px.

Or if the issue can't be told, can you recommend any kind of debugging best-practice for this kind of issue?

Thanks for help!

**editing**

link to see the issue: http://web.uni-corvinus.hu/~asdsma/index.html

(sorry, it is in my native language. You should compare the 1st and the 4th menu items for example.)

Comment: Check if you are in quirks mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627097/how-to-tell-if-a-browser-is-in-quirks-mode

Comment: It says I am in Standard Mode.

Comment: To check if the problem really isn't CSS try to disable it, in Firefox go to View > Page Style > No Style. I suspect it's definitely a CSS issue. Dev tool Inspector should be able to narrow it down. Do you see a horizontal scrollbar? If you do then some content is leaking out of its container. You can point the Inspector to the extra space and see which element it selects.

Comment: I literally deleted everything in Developer mode and the 17px difference stayed. Unless I delete the part i put in here as code, the issue stays.

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about the scroll bar?

Comment: OH. MY. GOD. I AM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I must go to sleep right now! You are the greatest, I would have never noticed. Jesus

Answer (score 0):

ARe you using any Client side library(e.g bootstrap) , the lib- css file will have some default css for elements which might be overriding your elements. Also please lear your browser cache , sometimes the css and js are cached.

Comment: I am not using anything else than self-written html, css and js. Cleared it, it persisted. :(

Comment: i don't see much code in the above section to tell whats  missing in the css . you can also try by  setting left and right  margin to -15px  to oveerride the exsisting css